# The render does not reload after a wavesurfer event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I have a site in React and I use [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) to play an audio. 
I have to realize a certain behavior when the audio enters a region.
For that wavesurfer provides the event [region-in](https://wavesurfer-js.org/example/annotation/index.html)
After the execution of my method the render is not reloaded, while I change a state.

```js
wavesurferObj.on('region-in', (region) => {
setCurrentRegion(region)
});
```

But render is reloaded after another event saving what happened before.